# How to set pdf font size for table content using jspdf?

Tags: jspdf, jspdf-autotable

How to set pdf font size for table content using jspdf?

setFontSize doesn't work in my case.

Answer (score 3):

Setting font size for text in a table using jspdf-autotable looks like this:

```
var doc = new jsPDF();
doc.autoTable({html: '#table', styles: {fontSize: 20}})
doc.save("table.pdf");
```

Comment: why ngFor doesnt work in jspdf autotable is there any solution

Answer (score 1):

Edit this: jspdf.plugin.autotable.min.js

Find this part and edit fontSize: `textColor:20,halign:"left",valign:"top",fontSize:10,cellPadding:5`

the default size is 10 and I change it to 7:
`textColor:20,halign:"left",valign:"top",fontSize:7,cellPadding:5`

Answer (score 0):

Before printing, make a copy of the table object.
Let's say:

let temporalTable = document.getElementsByClassName("table")[0];

Then apply a style to this object. You can use plain JS functions.

And finally:

```
    html2canvas(temporalTableWithNewStyles)
    .then((canvas: any) => {
        doc.addImage(canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg"), "JPEG", 0, 50, doc.internal.pageSize.width, element.offsetHeight / 5 );
        doc.save(`Report-${Date.now()}.pdf`);
    })
```

Comment: Thx Leonardo, in this way can we use jquery clone?

Comment: I didn't try it but I guess a deep copy is not a bad idea : )

Answer (score 0):

Are you using jspdf-autotable? If so you have to set `bodyStyles` instead of `styles`

```
bodyStyles:{
    fontSize:9
},
```

It's explained in [the docs](https://github.com/simonbengtsson/jsPDF-AutoTable?tab=readme-ov-file#styling-options).